# histogram with multiple binary variables

Tags: r, plot, histogram

I have a dataset where columns represents variables and rows interviewers.
I have 5 binary variables indicating the region where the respondent comes from (Central, South, North, East, Ovest). Central is 1 if the individual lives there, 0 otherwise. The same for the other 4 dummies.

I want to visualize a bar plot or histogram, where on the y axis I have the absolute frequencies, and on the x axis I have two sub sections, 0 and 1. For each subsection I need a bar of the absolute frequencies for Central when is 0, a bar of the absolute frequencies for South when is 0, and so on. The same for the sub section 1.

[Like in the figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJMoT.png)

Comment: You could just convert your dummy variables into a factor. See this previous answer [Recoding dummy variable to ordered factor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14161202/4752675)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get a faster response if you provide a reproducible data set. From your description, you data seems to be something like this:

```
set.seed(42)
x <- sample.int(5, 15, replace=TRUE)
dta <- matrix(0, 15, 5)
dta[cbind(1:15, x)] <- 1
colnames(dta) <- c("Central", "South", "North", "East", "Ovest")
head(dta)
#      Central South North East Ovest
# [1,]       1     0     0    0     0
# [2,]       0     0     0    0     1
# [3,]       1     0     0    0     0
# [4,]       1     0     0    0     0
# [5,]       0     1     0    0     0
# [6,]       0     0     0    1     0
```

You want to produce bar plots for each region:

```
freq <- colSums(dta)
bars <- rbind(Present=freq, Absent=nrow(dta) - freq)
#         Central South North East Ovest
# Present       5     5     0    3     2
# Absent       10    10    15   12    13
barplot(bars, beside=TRUE, legend=TRUE)
```

[image: Barplot]